# Generate Form from exist Entity Symfony4

Tags: forms, entity, symfony4

I have a table in the database which has a large number of columns. I know that  EasyAdminBundle is out there and I used it in the past to create forms based on database tables. How can create this based on Entity? So that I can generate the forms automatically and no populate them manually.

Comment: don`t want to use easyadminbundle i created my own, any idea how to handle forms basics on Entity, Database table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Symfony Maker Bundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle). With this bundle, you can generate code if you are using a version of Symfony later than 3.4. For older versions you can use [Sensio Generator Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html).

In your case, install the Maker Bundle with composer:

```
composer require symfony/maker-bundle --dev
```

Then run this command (and follow the steps) to create your form:

```
php bin/console make:form
```

To see all *make commands* you can use, run `php bin/console list make`

Answer (score 0):

As symfony 4.4 you can do :

./bin/console make:entity YourFormType \\Your\\Path\\To\\Entity

From the command help :

Description:
  Creates a new form class

Usage:

```
make:form [ <name> [<bound-class>]]
```